# Should I use .NET (System.Net.Mail) to batch send my web application's emails or SQL (msdb.sp_send_dbmail)?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2008, email

**Scenario:**

1) My application is a .NET 3.5 C# web app and the database is SQL 2008.

2) Emails will be in the region of 100 to 1000 a day and are triggered by various web user interactions with the app.

3) Most emails will contain attachment(s) between 50KB and 5MB. Some emails will be HTML and some will be plain text.

4) All attachments will be sourced from a directory on the web server.

5) The SQL server is a separate machine to the Web Server. All SQL connections from the application are via SQL logins not Windows Authentication.

6) For a scalable solution, Emails to be sent will be queued in a database table ready for a batch process to pickup. Failed emails should be retried up to 4 times.

**Dilemma:**

I'm not sure whether to write a web server solution to send emails (e.g. a windows service which polls the emails ready to send) or maybe to use SQL database mail which is easy to setup and use and doesn't require much development.

The fact the attachments sit on the web server suggests to me to use a web server solution but I would be interested to see if I've missed something.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, be wary about sending 1000s of emails a day in bursts. That's a good way to get blacklisted from other mail servers or even your Internet provider. Second, I'd recommend going the .NET routine. This problem smacks of a service. Even if you do not build it as a service today, you may want to do so at some point in the future. With .NET, you could refactor your solution to send emails in parallel or access the queue in a multi-threaded way. All of this would be difficult in SQL Server.  In short, .NET gives you the ability to make a more extensible solution than SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

I think you've answered your own question. As you've chosen to queue the emails in the database IMO there would be little advantage to creating a managed solution on the webserver in order to send the emails.

The one thing I'd consider is the fact you're storing the attachments on the webserver, this means there would be more network traffic between webserver and database than if the webserver were sending the emails (assuming they run on different physical servers). Using your figures that could be 5GB traffic per day in attachments. However, I'd go with the DB solution and test it rigorously to see if traffic becomes a problem. If so, you haven't lost much dev time on the DB solution.

Comment: I'd agree with this, keep it simple.

Comment: This is certainly an option I'd like to test. My problem is that I'm not even sure that the database server would have permissions to the files on the web server as the communication between the 2 servers is via SQL logins not windows.

Comment: It'll depend on the Windows account SQL server itself is running under.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I've asked around and noone is 100% sure but the consesus is that the live setup we have is very locked down with the web server being fairly untrusted by anything other than a SQL DB connection. The test and training environments have different IIS / SQL setups as well - This leads me to think that the DB route offers too many potential network traffic and/or permission problems on the various deployment enrironments: the day or two of writing a .net web service may prove to be the more reliable solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with .NET instead of sending emails from the DB.  Sending emails in .NET is super-simple also, and won't require any kind of extensive setup or development time.

On a related note, I have no idea why SQL Server can send emails, as this functionality does not seem to fit within the data storage model.  Does SQL Server also do 3D rendering?

Comment: +1 for 3d rendering lol, I would take a wild guess that the email feature is probably there to support SQL admins/developers to easily implement any kind of email alert without requiring any knowledge of programming outside the query language they already know well